# "От-кутюр" чи "от кутюр"?

Tags: запозичені-слова, орфографія, orthography, разом-дефіс-окремо

Цей термін є транскрипцією <sub>фр.</sub> [*haute couture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haute_couture). В нас його перекладають як [*висока мода*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Але якщо транскрибують, то зустрічаються обидва варіянти написання:

- *от кутюр* (наприклад, [в назві книги](http://nashformat.ua/catalog/knygy/knyga_revolyutsiya_ot_kutyur_dmytro_korchynskyj/))
- *от-кутюр* (наприклад, [в Авраменка](http://xn--80aafnzkijm.xn--j1amh/11/12/262-urok-108-suknia-vd-kutiur-chi-ot-kutiur.html))

В словниках (окрім народних) слово не ґуґлиться.

Цікаво, що в [російському wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%80) бачимо примітку <sub>(це важливо, бо українська вікі про високу моду є перекладом з російської)</sub>:

> Данное написание не соответствует ныне действующей норме.
>   Нормативное написание: от-кутюр

Чи є в нас норми щодо транскрибування іншомовних слів? Бо як на мене, якщо в оригіналі пишеться в два слова, то й в нас має бути так само (на відміну від *prêt-à-porter*).

Comment: А ще ж пишуть разом, [_откутюр_](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=french+ukrainian+dictionary&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#lr=lang_uk&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&q=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%80%22&*). Як на мене, таке написання найкраще, ми ж пишемо _шезлонг_ разом, хоча французькою це 2 окремі слова «chaise longue», довгий стілець. І це транскрипція, а не транслітерація.

Comment: @YellowSky, а ще пишуть «[від кутюр](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22від+кутюр%22)» і «[откутюрний](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22откутюрний%22)».

Comment: @Sasha - Ага, перше то вже гіпкркорекція, це не для нас, а друге – то це заперечення твердження до [Анатолій Хлівний](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/784/66) про те, що ми тут маємо діло з варваризмом, а не з засвоєним запозиченням.

Comment: @YellowSky, я мав на увазі, що люди по-всякому пишуть, але не всяке є нормою. (Хоча те, як люди пишуть, звісно, впливає на норму.)

Answer (score 10):

*"От кутюр"* треба писати окремо, бо це не складне слово, а варваризм -  вислів французької мови, переданий українськими буквами. Аналогія зі *"шезлонгом"* недоречна, адже *"шезлонг"* - засвоєне українською мовою слово, що чудово відмінюється.

Ось що пише про написання варваризму *"а ля"* [Катерина Городенська](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/42834/21-Gorodenska4.pdf?sequence=1):

> **Як все-таки правильно писати а ля?**
>   Подібність до кого-, чого-небудь, стилізацію під когось чи щось в українській мові виражають прикметники *схожий, подібний*, порівняльні сполучники *наче, неначе, ніби, мов, мовби* й ін. та порівняльні прийменники *подібно до, на зразок, на взірець, на кшталт* тощо.
>
> Крім цих відомих засобів дехто використовує незвичне утворення **а ля**, що за своєю будовою копіює поєднання прийменника а та артикля *ля* у французькій мові. Воно має розмовне, переважно іронічне забарвлення.
>
> Але пишуть його досі неоднаково:
>   **або через дефіс**, услід за деякими орфографічними та іншими словниками (Український орфографічний словник. – К., 2008 – С. 21; Словник українських прийменників. – Донецьк, 2007. – С. 23), **або окремо**, порівняйте:
>
> *Це потрібно групі, яка має на меті розбавити середовище, зробити схему а-ля Кучма 2003–2004 роки* (Газета по-українськи, 21.12.2010);
>   *А в колекції з однойменної тканини були виготовлені і куртки, і светри, і комбінезони, і лосини. Червоні спідниці із чорною бахромою поверх а ля Мулен Руж...* (Україна молода, 13.10.2001).
>
> Писати *а ля* через дефіс в
>   українській літературній мові немає підстав, бо це не складне слово.
>   Воно є варваризмом, тобто сполукою французької мови, переданою
>   літерами української мови. Саме тому його потрібно писати окремо.

Comment: Незрозуміло, як Катерина Городенська обґрунтовує те, що варваризми мають писатися окремо (чи то — як в оригіналі). Але це питання вже не до Вас, а до Катерини Городенської…

Answer (score 7):

> Новий словник іншомовних слів: близько 40000 сл. і словосполучень / Л. І. Шевченко , О. І. Ніка , О. І. Хом'як , А. А. Дем'янюк; За ред Л. І. Шевченко — К.: АРІЙ, 2008. — 672 с. — ISBN 978-966-498-027-9

має наступну статтю:

> **ОТ-КУТЮ́Р** (фр haut coutur, від haut = *букв.* висота + coutur = шиття) — 1) висока мода; 2) творці високої моди, художники-модельєри, що створюють напрямки у світовій моді; 3) моделі одягу, створювані такими майстрами (пор. прет-а-порте).

[image: Словникова стаття "от-кутюр"]

А щоб усім остаточно стало весело

> Великий зведений орфографічний словник сучасної української лексики: 253 000 слів / В. Т. Бусел, М. Д. Василега-Дерибас, О. В. Дмитрієв, Г. В. Латник, Г. В. Степенко; За ред. В. Т. Бусел — Ірпінь: Перун, 2008 — 887 с. — ISBN 966-569-178-3

і взагалі ліпить

> **від-кутю́р**, *невідм.*

[image: Словникова стаття "від-кутюр"]

але все-таки через дефіс :)

Comment: Бусел і «Перун» відомі видянням сумнозвісного [ВТССУМ](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Великий_тлумачний_словник_сучасної_української_мови), які дехто сприймає як плагіат СУМ-11 низької якості. (Хоча, по-моєму, вони перебільшують — при оформленні ВТССУМ все ж було виконано великий обсяг роботи — але таке сприйняття їхньої роботи існує, і, можливо, якась доля правди в ньому і є.)

Comment: Щодо «от-кутюр» у словнику 2008 — цікаво. Може — це й справді нова норма (наприклад, в рос. змінилося — і наші навздогін), а може — просто помилка в словнику. Цікаво, як співвідноситься авторитетність словників Мазніченка (2000) і Шевченка (2008).

Answer (score 5):

В статті [«Висока мода» у Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&oldid=18715962) є посилання на джерело написання:

> Словник іншомовних слів / Уклад.: С. М. Морозов, Л. М. Шкарапута.— К.: Наукова думка, 2000. — 680с. — (Словники України). ISBN 966-00-0439-7

В тому джерелі написано:

> **ОТ КУТЮ́Р** (від франц. haut coutur, від haut, букв. — висота i coutur — шиття) — висока мода.

Заходимо знов у Вікіпедію, дивимось історію, бачимо, що 3 березня 2016‎, незважаючи на наявність джерела, користувач [зробив помилкове редагування](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&diff=17707149), замінивши всі «от кутюр» на «от-кутюр». На його захист можна сказати, що в тій версії, на якій базувалось його редагування, посилання стояло в доволі неочікуваному місці (здавалось, що воно обґрунтовує походження слова, а не написання).

[Виправляємо Вікіпедію](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&type=revision&diff=19861811&oldid=18715962).

Щодо загальних правил — не знаю. Можливо, [Анатолій Хлівний правий](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/784/4), що **варваризми** наслідують оце «разом чи дефісно чи окремо» з оригінального написання. Повністю адаптовані запозичення, звісно, **не** наслідують це зі слова-оригінала (*<sub>фр.</sub>* Eau de Cologne: <s>О де Колон, О де Колону, О де Колоном, в О де Колоні</s> одеколон, одеколону, одеколоном, в одеколоні).

Comment: Гіперкореція: *«о, де ж цей Колон?»*

Answer (score 5):

Продивився я *повністю* Словник іншомовних слів (Уклад.: С. М. Морозов, Л. М. Шкарапута), звертаючи увагу на всі словосполучення, що пишуться окремо.

**От кутюр** - це єдиний випадок, де обидва "слова" не можуть використовуються окремо в українській мові у відповідному значення (є тільки кутюр'є, "[от](http://sum.in.ua/s/ot)" не має відповідного смислу).

Найбільш цікаві словосполучення, що не мають українських суффіксів, чи інших особливостей українського словотворення:

- **А-ля фуршет** - по-перше слово "фуршет" може використовуватися окремо, по-друге - маємо приклад використання "**а-ля**" через дефіс;
- **Казус беллі** - "казус" може використовуватися окремо;
- **Казус федеріс** - так само;
- **Афіна Паллада** - варіант імені богині Афіни (тобто Афіна використовується окремо);
- **Сцилла і Харібда** - імена двох чудовиськ ("між Сциллою і Харібдою"), якщо об'єднати їх в одне слово буде не зрозуміло як можна опинитися між ними;

Інші словосполучення, де одне з слів має відповідний суфікс, а інше може використовуватися окремо (виділено жирним):

- Едипів **комплекс**;
- Кластерний **аналіз**;
- Мартенівський **процес**;
- Юрський **період**;
- Катарсичний **метод**;
- Доричний **ордер** (ордер - архітектурний стиль);
- тощо.

Отже "от кутюр" має унікальний вигляд як для словосполучення, що потрапило у словник. Напевно ця форма поки що є найбільш вживаною (можливо під впливом російського вжитку), але загальна тенденція - написання таких слів або через дефіс або разом.

Оскільки в словнику вказаний варіант "от кутюр", то саме такий варіант є правильним.

---

[image: Означення слів "казус"]

---

*(Нижче - стара відповідь на тему "якщо сперечатися із словником то...", цінність якої, як на мене, у прикладах різних написань іноземних слів, які не співпадають із іноземними відповідниками).*

На мою думку "а ля" (що виступає у ролі чи то прикметника, чи то порівняльного сполучника, чи то порівняльного прийменника) не може бути відповідником до "от кутюр", яке виступає у ролі іменника.

Якщо шукати відповідники до "от кутю́р" (фр. haute couture — «високе пошиття»), то можемо подивитися на написання через дефіс слів прет-а-порте, па-де-де, па-де-труа.

Всі ці слова - іменники французького походження, що не відмінюються (а отже підпадають під означення "варваризм"):

- [прет-а-порте](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5) (фр. prêt-à-porter) — «готове вбрання» (у СУМ-11 немає)
- [па-де-де](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5) (фр. pas de deux) — букв. «танок удвох» ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pa-de-de))
- [па-де-труа](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B0) (фр. pas de trois) — балетний танець для трьох виконавців, а також музика до нього ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pa-de-trua)).

У [правописі](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm) є розділ щодо [правопису слів іншомовного походження](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm), але у цьому розділі перелічені лише способи передачі звуків іншої мови, та способи відмінювання таких слів (і жодного слова про дефіс).

Єдиний розділ, що описує використання дефісу у іншомовних словах - правопис географічних назв:

> **[Написання через дефіс](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par114p3)**
>
> 3. Через дефіс пишуться:
>
>    в) географічні назви, що складаються з іншомовних елементів — **повнозначних слів**, а також похідні від них прикметники: Буенос-Айрес, Думбартон-Окс, Іссик-Куль, Кзил-Орда, Нар’ян-Мар, Ріо-Негро, Улан-Уде; буенос-айреський та ін., але: Алатау, Амудар’я, Махачкала, Сирдар’я; ...
>
>    ґ) географічні назви, що складаються з іменників, які поєднуються українськими або іншомовними прийменниками, сполучниками чи мають при собі частку, /150/ артикль, а також утворені від них прикметники: Новосілки-на-Дніпрі, Ростов-на-Дону, Франкфурт-на-Майні, Яр-під-Зайчиком; Булонь-сюр-Мер, Бург-ель-Араб, Ла-Манш, Ла-Плата, Лас-Вегас, Лос-Анджелес, **Па-де-Кале**, Ріо-де-Жанейро, Сен-е-Уаз (департамент); новосілківський-на-Дніпрі, ростовський-на-Дону, франкфуртський-на-Майні, ярський-під-зайчиком; булонь-сюр-мерський, бург-ель-арабський, ла-маншський, ла-платський і т. ін.;

Зверніть увагу на Па-де-Кале (фр. Pas de Calais, Дуврська протока), що співпадає по "конструкції" із па-де-де (pas de deux) та па-де-труа (pas de trois) - як в українському так і у французькому варіанті.

Чи можна в таких випадках користуватися правилами написання дефісу для географічних назв? Це дивне питання, але чому географічні назви пишеться в такому разі через дефіс?

Моя думка така що географічна назва пишеться через дефіс щоб показати що це - одна сутність. Так само па-де-де, па-де-труа - іменники, що є назвами танців.

Прет-а-порте - також одна сутність. Haute couture теж виступає у ролі іменника, є однією сутністю, а отже використання дефісу підкреслить те, що це - сполучені частини одного поняття. Тим більше що обидва поняття походять з французької мови і мають відношення до моди.

До того ж таке написання знімає питання "гіперкоррекції" і позначає "от" як частину слова, а не російський прийменник.

---

Ще декілька назв танців:

- [падекатр](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=18&t=25174) (фр. pas de quatre) — букв. «танок учотирьох». Бальний танок; у балеті - танок для чотирьох виконавців (несподіванка: удвох та утрьох через дефіс, а учотирьох - вже разом).
- [падеспань](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C) (фр. pas d'Espagne) — «іспанський крок»;
- [падеграс](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=18&t=25171) (фр. pas de grace) — бальний повільний танок, а також музика для нього.

Ці приклади показують ще один варіант, запропонований Yellow Sky - написання "откутюр" (також уникає гіперкоррекції).

Comment: «Казус беллі», «казус федеріс» — так і слово [казус](http://sum.in.ua/s/kazus) не має відповідного значення.

Comment: «Під впливом російського вжитку» — так у російській [от-кутюр](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/от-кутюр).

Comment: «Haute couture теж виступає у ролі іменника, є однією сутністю, а отже використання дефісу підкреслить те, що це - сполучені частини одного поняття.» — це дуже логічно, але, на жаль, правила в мові не завжди логічні.

Comment: В цілому, -1. Хоч я би хотів, щоби писалося «от-кутюр» або «откутюр».

Comment: Казус - це випадок (а також юридичний термін). Казус беллі - випадок що призводить до війни. Казус федеріс - випадок, що призводить до вступу у війну за договором. В обох значеннях казус - зрозуміло що є таке іноземне слово. У слова "от" є 10 означень, жодне з яких не є іноземним і жодне з яких не має хоча б приблизно значення "мода" чи "високий" чи хоча-б що-небудь пов'язане.

Comment: @Sasha У російській от-кутюр стало нормативним не так давно. У російському корпусі "от-кутюр" через дефіс взагалі немає.

Comment: Все ж можу помилятися, але казус (в українській мові) — це смішний/курйозний випадок або складна судова справа (або специфічний юр. термін). Я би в таких випадках (за наявності в українській мові *схожих* слів, але з трішки іншими значеннями) в першу чергу писав разом/дефісно (щоб уникнути неправильної конотації) і вже вдругу — у випадках, коли українські слова мають зовсім інше значення (як з «от»). Ну, якби я, звісно, мав право це вирішувати, був уклададев словників. (Крім того, Ви опускаєте, що і слів «беллі»/«федеріс» немає — вже через це «варто» було б писати не окремо.)

Comment: «У російській от-кутюр стало нормативним не так давно. У російському корпусі "от-кутюр" через дефіс взагалі немає.» — прийнято, був неправий.

Comment: В цілому, мені здається, що Ви пишете дуже логічні речі. Але мова конкретно від нас в першу чергу не залежить (а від (1) того, як де-факто люди пишуть; (2) рішень мовознавців). Хтозна, може, взагалі «відкутюрний» і «від кутюр'є» закріпляться — і плювати на оригінальну етимологію. А норма завжди відстає від новітніх тенденцій — а ми маємо висвітлювати норму (а то начитається нас людина і буде писати, як з нашої точки зору логічно — а її потім на сміх візьмуть.)

Comment: @Sasha згоден. Ну а нормою в данному випадку є словник, бажано орфографічний, бо правила щодо не географічних назв немає.

Answer (score 3):

[Варваризми](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC) — це запозичене чи створене за зразком якоїсь іншої мови слово або вираз, що **порушує норми цієї мови**. "От кутюр", як і "а ля", "альтер его", "ад хок", "альтер мода" (італійський відповідник до "от кутюр") саме такими словами і є. Адже, якщо "от кутюр" сприймати як звичайне запозичення (і писати його разом), то треба визнати, що це слово повністю засвоєне українською мовою. Отже, воно змінюється за відмінками, може мати множину, похідні слова тощо.

Нічого цього про "haute couture" ми сказати не можемо, важко навіть сказати, якого граматичного роду це слово: жіночого (як у мові-оригіналі), чоловічого (бо схоже на слова третьої дієвідміни) чи середнього (як слово з українського перекладу "високе шиття").

Ніхто не каже: тижні **откутюра** в Парижі; вона захоплена **откутюром**. Немає похідних слів: откутюрний, откутюрно, откутюрність тощо.

Comment: У Словнику Морозова й справді немає, але там немає і **а джіо́рно, а капела, а капіте, а темпо**, а от у [Словнику іншомовних слів Мельничука](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53392-0.html) такі слова є.